# calculates highest count words across lines error in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i am new in ruby and i have trouble doing this task it should calculates highest count words across lines 
there is my code. i tried for 2 months to solve it and i watched you tube videos about ruby and rest my deadlines in coursera 4 times pleas help

```
class LineAnalyzer


attr_reader :highest_wf_count, :highest_wf_words, :content, :line_number
  def initialize(line, line_number)
  @content = line
    @line_number = line_number
    self.calculate_word_frequency(line)
  end
def calculate_word_frequency(line)
  word_frequency = Hash.new(0)
  line.split.each do |word|
    word_frequency[word.downcase] += 1
  end
  @highest_wf_count = word_frequency.values.max
  if @highest_wf_count >1
  @highest_wf_words = word_frequency.select {|key,value| value == word_frequency.values.max}.keys
end
end
end

class Solution
  attr_reader :analyzers, :highest_count_across_lines, :highest_count_words_across_lines, :highest_count_across_lines
 def initialize
  @analyzers = []
  @highest_count_words_across_lines =nil

  end
  def analyze_file
    text = File.open("./test.txt", "r")
    text.each_line do |line|
    @analyzers << line
    end
  end


  def calculate_line_with_highest_frequency
    c=[]
    @arr = {}
    @analyzers.each_with_index do |line, index|
     lll = LineAnalyzer.new(line,index)
      @arr[lll.highest_wf_words] = lll.highest_wf_count
      if lll.highest_wf_words != nil
       c.push(lll.highest_wf_words)#кол-во встречаний
    end
  end
    x=c.join(" ")
     x=x.split
     z =x[1]
     b =x[2]
     d =x[0]
     x[0] =z
     x[1] =b
     x[2] =d

       @highest_count_words_across_lines =x


    @highest_count_across_lines = @arr.values.max#4


    end


def print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines

  puts  @highest_count_words_across_lines

end
end
```

there is the solution_spec

```
r

equire_relative "../module2_assignment"
require 'rspec'

describe Solution do
  subject(:solution) { Solution.new }

  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:analyze_file) } 
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:calculate_line_with_highest_frequency) } 
  it { is_expected.to respond_to(:print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines) } 

  context "#analyze_file" do
    it "creates 3 line analyzers" do
      expect(solution.analyzers.length).to eq 0 
      solution.analyze_file
      expect(solution.analyzers.length).to eq 3
    end  
  end

  context "#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency" do


    it "calculates highest count across lines to be 4" do
      solution.analyze_file

      expect(solution.highest_count_across_lines).to be nil

      solution.calculate_line_with_highest_frequency

      expect(solution.highest_count_across_lines).to be 4
    end  
    it "calculates highest count words across lines to be will, it, really" do
      solution.analyze_file

      expect(solution.highest_count_words_across_lines).to be nil

      solution.calculate_line_with_highest_frequency

      words_found = solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map(&:highest_wf_words).flatten
      expect(words_found).to match_array ["will", "it", "really"] 
    end  
  end

end
```

and there is the line_analyzer_spec

```
    require_relative "../module2_assignment"
require 'rspec'

describe LineAnalyzer do
  subject(:lineAnalyzer) { LineAnalyzer.new("test", 1) }

  it "has accessor for highest_wf_count" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:highest_wf_count) 
  end 
  it "has accessor for highest_wf_words" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:highest_wf_words) 
  end
  it "has accessor for content" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:content) 
  end
  it "has accessor for line_number" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:line_number) 
  end
  it "has method calculate_word_frequency" do
    is_expected.to respond_to(:calculate_word_frequency) 
  end
  context "attributes and values" do
  it "has attributes content and line_number" do
    is_expected.to have_attributes(content: "test", line_number: 1) 
  end
  it "content attribute should have value \"test\"" do
    expect(lineAnalyzer.content).to eq("test")
  end
  it "line_number attribute should have value 1" do
    expect(lineAnalyzer.line_number).to eq(1)
  end
end

  it "calls calculate_word_frequency when created" do
    expect_any_instance_of(LineAnalyzer).to receive(:calculate_word_frequency)
    LineAnalyzer.new("", 1) 
  end

  context "#calculate_word_frequency" do
    subject(:lineAnalyzer) { LineAnalyzer.new("This is a really really really cool cool you you you", 2) }

    it "highest_wf_count value is 3" do
      expect(lineAnalyzer.highest_wf_count).to eq(3)
    end
    it "highest_wf_words will include \"really\" and \"you\"" do
      expect(lineAnalyzer.highest_wf_words).to include 'really', 'you'
    end
    it "content attribute will have value \"This is a really really really cool cool you you you\"" do
      expect(lineAnalyzer.content).to eq("This is a really really really cool cool you you you")
    end
    it "line_number attribute will have value 2" do
      expect(lineAnalyzer.line_number).to eq(2)
    end
  end
end
```

and there is the error

```
    /shared/submission/anything.zip: 0 tests run
["\n", "LineAnalyzer\n", "  has accessor for highest_wf_count\n", "  has
["\accessor for highest_wf_words\n", "  has accessor for content\n", "  has
["\accessor for line_number\n", "  has method calculate_word_frequency\n", " 
["\calls calculate_word_frequency when created\n", "  attributes and
["\values\n", "    has attributes content and line_number\n", "    content
["\attribute\n", "    line_number attribute\n", " 
["\#calculate_word_frequency\n", "    highest_wf_count value is 3\n", "   
["\highest_wf_words check\n", "    content attribute will have expected
["\value\n", "    line_number attribute\n", "\n", "Solution\n", "  should
["\respond to #analyze_file\n", "  should respond to
["\#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency\n", "  should respond to
["\#print_highest_word_frequency_across_lines\n", "  #analyze_file\n", "   
["\creates 3 line analyzers\n", "  #calculate_line_with_highest_frequency\n",
["\"    calculates highest count across lines to be 4\n", "    calculates
["\highest count words across lines to be will, it, really (FAILED - 1)\n",
["\"\n", "Failures:\n", "\n", "  1)
["\Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count
["\words across lines to be will, it, really\n", "     Failure/Error:
["\words_found =
["\solution.highest_count_words_across_lines.map(&:highest_wf_words).flatten\n",
["\"\n", "     NoMethodError:\n", "       undefined method `highest_wf_words'
["\for \"will\":String\n", "     # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:39:in `map'\n", "  
["\  # ./spec/solution_spec.rb:39:in `block (3 levels) in <top
["\(required)>'\n", "\n", "Finished in 0.01251 seconds (files took 0.09799
["\seconds to load)\n", "19 examples, 1 failure\n", "\n", "Failed
["\examples:\n", "\n", "rspec ./spec/solution_spec.rb:32 #
["\Solution#calculate_line_with_highest_frequency calculates highest count
["\words across lines to be will, it, really\n", "\n"][]
```

Comment: When does the error come ? While running the code or the tests ? Please do read [How to ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @AlokSwain the error come when i submit it to coursera's grader 
and thanks for the recommendation